# flask-images generating image error for some images

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I've built a flask site and it's been working for over a year, but I've just encountered an image that is not correctly resizing when using flask images to generate a resized image. The static image loads correctly, so I can only assume it's an error with the flask-images resizing. I can't find any way to see the exact error and so I'm kind of stuck in troubleshooting. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Error:
The image [image] cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Example of broken image:

Resized URL:
https://www.eskimotv.net/imgsizer/img/cover-images/zack-snyder-s-justice-league-still-sucks-2021-cover-image.jpg?h=466&m=crop&v=YHMxhA&w=994&s=b%27vYAlpffxM8wbfIREZG62hM5XzIw%27

Functioning static resource:
https://www.eskimotv.net/static/img/cover-images/zack-snyder-s-justice-league-still-sucks-2021-cover-image.jpg

Example of it working fine for other images:

Resized URL:
https://www.eskimotv.net/imgsizer/img/cover-images/hellboy-2019-cover-image.jpg?h=466&m=crop&v=Xtmyyw&w=994&s=b%27JYX9u5-jNkVgzcqvZlA-kObl7QU%27

Static resource:
https://www.eskimotv.net/static/img/cover-images/hellboy-2019-cover-image.jpg

Resize code:

```
<img class="img-responsive webfeedsFeaturedVisual" src="{{ resized_img_src(article.image,width=994,height=466,mode='crop') }}" alt="{{ article.title }} Cover">
```

Edit:

By running the server locally and viewing the error log I was able to identify the following error at the time when flask-images was attempting to generate the cached version of the resized image:

```
web_1  | 172.18.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2021 02:06:54] "GET /imgsizer/img/cover-images/short-cover-image.jpg?h=466&m=crop&v=YHT8vQ&w=994&s=b%27U8Rbw9xy3J63t0mPW3NHN
aNfSCo%27 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/home/eskimotv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 633, in _save
web_1  |     rawmode = RAWMODE[im.mode]
web_1  | KeyError: 'RGBA'
web_1  |
web_1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
web_1  |
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/home/eskimotv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
web_1  |     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
web_1  |   File "/home/eskimotv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
web_1  |     response = self.handle_exception(e)
web_1  |   File "/home/eskimotv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
web_1  |     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
web_1  |   File "/home/eskimotv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
web_1  |     raise value
web_1  |   File "/home/eskimotv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
web_1  |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
web_1  |   File "/home/eskimotv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
web_1  |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
web_1  |   File "/home/eskimotv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
web_1  |     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
web_1  |   File "/home/eskimotv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
web_1  |     raise value
web_1  |   File "/home/eskimotv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
web_1  |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
web_1  |   File "/home/eskimotv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
web_1  |     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
web_1  |   File "/home/eskimotv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_images/core.py", line 428, in handle_request
web_1  |     image.save(cache_file, format, quality=quality)
web_1  |   File "/home/eskimotv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2172, in save
web_1  |     save_handler(self, fp, filename)
web_1  |   File "/home/eskimotv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 635, in _save
web_1  |     raise OSError(f"cannot write mode {im.mode} as JPEG") from e
web_1  | OSError: cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue 1: Regarding finding and viewing the error: I was able to find and view the error generated by pillow by running the flask server locally and viewing the log. I will add the full error to the question.

Issue 2: Regarding the issue with the image. The image generating the error had an alpha layer of some kind from when it was saved to the static directory even though it was being saved as a jpg. While I do not have transparency into the flask-images method for generating cached resized images, I did have access to the method that saved the external image to my server. So, when saving the static content, I simply added this line in the method for saving images locally to convert the image before saving it:

```
img = img.convert("RGB")
```

This was based on this issue with Python Pillow:

https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2609

This way the static source is fully compatible with the resized images method for flask-images by discarding the transparency layer.